# UIWebView not full screen on rotate

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, uiwebview

(This looks like a question that has been asked/answered 100 times but I can't get it to work.)

I have a view controller that is story board based. Nested in the main view is a webUIView.

In the controller method viewDidLoad I am simply specifying the URL and setting the view and the webUIView to autoresize:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"web_app_build"]];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_browser loadRequest:request];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = TRUE;
    self.browser.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

I also added this method

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.browser.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

When I rotate the device the webUIView rotates, but doesn't resize to fill the screen. I did try writing my own rotation handler but this seems the entirely wrong way to do that.

I did read the [apple doc on the topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html). How can I make the webUIview resize to fit the display size on rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that `self.view.bounds` has most likely not been adjusted yet to the bounds after rotation. Set a breakpoint to check this out. I would move the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` instead. If you don't need to support versions of iOS before iOS 6, I'd strongly recommend looking into using Auto Layout for your view objects. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`  instead of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` did make the difference.